# Magento 2 CentOS 7 nginx -> varnish -> apache -> php-fpm redirect loop

Tags: apache, magento, nginx, centos7, varnish

I've been messing with this for two days and can't find the magical combination.

I'm using Magento 2 on CentOS 7 with nginx handling SSL passing off to varnish on port 80 which passes on to apache on 8080 which uses php-fpm.  I can get Magento to work with just varnish -> apache -> php-fpm but when I try to introduce nginx in the mix to handle the SSL I get a redirect loop on the entire site.  I've found all kinds of suggestions here and other places but nothing seems to fix it.

Does anyone have a good guide or any direction on what to do here?  Can post configs if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Please try by clearing your cookies, most of the time it does fix for me.

Comment: Done that.  Cleared the Magento cache as well via command line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's hard to say anything without seeing the code and what redirect you're getting exactly. But if I would have to bet you're missing an `x-forwarded-proto` header so PHP assumes you connected with HTTP and sends you to HTTPS. Try this in your Varnish configuration:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  ...
  set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";
  ...
}
```